# Makefile doesn't see -pthread?

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, pthreads

I have the following makefile:

```
all: file

prog: file.c
     gcc file.c -o file -pthread
```

However upon hitting "make" in the terminal I am getting "error, undefinted reference to pthread_create".

But when I type into the terminal "`gcc file.c -o file -pthread`" it works.

Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you mean to write "file" and "prog"?

Comment: Silly me, that solved it, thanks!